# How to avoid having blur display with correct font size (in em)

Tags: css, fonts

Currently, in my CSS, I using the following font size

```
font: .74em "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif
```

However, in selected machine with selected browser, it doesn't display sharp enough, with selected font size.

### Lenovo with Chrome, font size .74em (Blur)

[image]

---

### Lenovo with Chrome, font size .75em (OK)

[image]

---

### Lenovo with IE, font size .74em (OK)

[image]

In Apple with retina display, it looks sharp all the time regardless font size.

I was wondering, how can we choose the correct font size, to avoid the display outcome from becoming blur?

Comment: did you try font-smooth property?

Comment: This issue would take me several chapters in a book to properly go over in greater detail.  The issue has to do with antialising, specifically with fonts coming back through the Windows GDI.  Easy fix should be to force an aliasing mode, using webkit-font-aliasing (try 'subpixel-antialiased').   There are similar things for IE, but it doesn't look like you're having problems with that.